# redux - action to fill an array and then reset

Tags: arrays, redux

I am trying to fill a small array [Should have two elements]. The initial state is

```
selected: []
```

Once it fills 2 slots [a, b], it should compare if the numbers are equal (return true or false) and reset the array to the original state [].

```
export const selectTile = (idx) => {
  return {
    type: SELECT_TILE,
    idx
  };
};


const initialState = {
  selected: [],
  matched: 0,
  score: 0
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_TILE:
      return { ...state, selected: state.selected.push(action.idx) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I have already stumbled upon the first problem. The above reducer returns an error 'state.selected.push is not a function'.

When the first action gets dispatched, it should do:

1. check if the array's length is smaller than 2
2. If yes, push the element to the array:

   selected: [x]

another action:

1. check if the array's length is smaller than 2
2. yes, push the element to the array:

   selected: [x, y]

another action:

1. check if the array's length is smaller than 2
2. no - compare if x === y, (return something, eg. true or false or any flag)
3. regardless of whether x===y or not, reset the 'selected' array to [] and wait for another action.

EDIT:

I think my description above was not accurate (btw, an action is dispatched on click of a tile):

> action 1: [x]
>
> action 2: [x, y] (if x=y, matched: true, selected: [])
>
> action 3: [x] (the moment this action is dispatched, it should clear
>   the 'selected' array and a new element should be added to the array.
>   As it stands with the answer below, the third actions just clears the
>   array, but no new element is added.

I have adapted the answer below but it gives me an error that state.slice is not an action (error appears when I click on a tile for the second time (action 2 being dispatched).

```
case SELECT_TILE:
      if (state.selected.length < 1) {
            return { ...state, selected: [...state.selected, action.idx] };
      } else if (state.selected.length === 1) {
            const nextState = state.slice();
            nextState.selected.concat(action.idx);
            if (nextState.selected[0] === nextState.selected[1]) {
              return { ...nextState, score: nextState.score + 1, selected: [] };
            }
            return { ...nextState, selected: [] };
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use concat to push an item to the state array as it retun

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_TILE:
      return { ...state, selected: state.selected.concat(action.idx) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

or you can do it with the spread operator itself, which i think is a better way

```
  return { ...state, selected: [...state.selected, action.idx] };
```

As per your requirement is considered

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_TILE:
      if(state.selected.length < 2) {
            return { ...state, selected: [...state.selected, action.idx] };
      } else {
           if(state.selected[0] === state.selected[1]) {
                return {...state, matched: true, selected: []}
           }
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you - I think I'm starting to get the logic. I've edited my question.

Comment: Nevermind. Thanks. I've realised that the second value does not need to be concatenated with the array, the comparison can be done between selected[0] and action.idx which solves the problem